# Specifying JBoss HTTP-404 error page

Tags: java, servlets, error-handling, jboss5.x

Is it possible to change the JBoss HTTP-404 error to a custom page where i can also check what the user was looking for and offer suggestions? JBoss 5.1.0.GA

Comment: You probably should post on ServerFault instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add following content in

```
 jboss-4.0.0/server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat50.sar/web.xml
```

file

```
<error-page>   
<error-code>404</error-code>   
<location>/pagenotfound.jsp</location>   
</error-page>  
<error-page>   
<error-code>500</error-code>   
<location>/servererror.jsp</location>  
</error-page>
```

Comment: thanks but as specified in the question, i'm using JBoss 5.1.0.GA

Comment: @n002213f In 5.0.x and 5.1.0, the global web.xml file is located at server/xxx/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml

Comment: where would i place the error pages? Instead of the JBoss error pages, nothing is shown.

Comment: @n002213f at the same location where default pages resides you can put your customized pages

Comment: thats the location i'm looking for.

Comment: @n002213f I don't have JBoss installed at this moment on my machine, you can do one thing search for 500.html or something like  that you will get one

Comment: These error reports are generated using using the ErrorReportValve, http://bit.ly/ias68V

Comment: @n002213f didn't get your comment

Comment: Please edit your answer to reflect the version in the question!